# Is it possible to create different spaces for different users in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am new to redshift, and i don't know if it is possible.

I have few users in database, let say admin and xyz

Q: Both users firing queries at a time, so is it possible to do some kind of setting which says provide 80% bandwidth to admin and 20% to xyz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  You'll want to configure Workload Management.  We've used it successfully for some time.  Detail documentation can be found [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-implementing-workload-management.html)